# python passing by reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, pass-by-reference

Strange things happens today when I do things like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = a

b[0] = 0

print a, b
```

And then the value seems to be passed by reference! The answer becomes:

```
result: [0 2 3] [0 2 3]
```

But usually I think the variable in python is passed by value, like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = a

b = np.array([0, 2, 3])

print a, b
```

And then the answer becomes:

```
result: [1 2 3] [0 2 3]
```

But why is that happenning? How do I decide whether the variable is passed through reference or value? Some people said it was because of the mutable object, but I still don't quite get it. So can you explain it for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's strange about that to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Assignment **never** makes a copy in Python. That's always how it works. Your second example is working *exactly the same* as your first.

Comment: You assigned a new object, `np.array([0, 2, 3])`, to `b` in the second case, instead of changing the original object. More spcifically, if you write `b = None` or `b = 10` in the second case, it will do nothing to `a`, that's reasonable.

Comment: Also, this isn't about evaluation strategy, but about how assignment works in Python. Read [Python has names, not variables](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). Also, check out [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 3):

As it doesn't have anything directly to do with NumPy, let's rewrite it as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = a

b = [0, 2, 3]

print a, b
```

The key thing is that names and values are separate things. So on the first line:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

You create a list and assign it to `a`

[image]

Now on the next line you assign `a` to `b`. There is still only 1 list, both names simply refer to it.

[image]

Next you create a new list and assign it to `b`. Now `b` refers to the new list instead of the *old* list. In turn now only 1 name (`a`) refers to the other list, instead of 2 names.

[image]

Thus if we take the first example, where you do:

```
b[0] = 0
```

There both `a` and `b` reference the same list, thus the change can be observed from both names, as both names refers to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignment in Python is always assignment to a reference. In other words, in Python, variables are names, and assigning a variable is declaring a name for something.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = a

b[0] = 0

print a, b
```

This means let `a` be the name for that first array, then let `b` be a name for `a`, but `a` means the first array, so really we're just saying let `b` also be a name for the first array. Then `b[0] = 0` means change the first element of the array. Then when you print `a` and `b`, you are printing the same thing twice (the array), because `a` and `b` are names for the same thing.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = a

b = np.array([0, 2, 3])

print a, b
```

The first two lines are the same as last time. `a` is a name for the array and so is `b`. Then `b = np.array([0, 2, 3])` means that `b` is now a name for this new array. So when you print `a` and `b` you are printing `a`, which is still the name for the first array, and `b`, which is the name for the second array.